# Using golden section search function for projectile motion optimization

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

I set up a golden search method to solve for optimal angle, and the maximum distance at any user defined initial velocity for a projectile motion problem.

first I created a function name

```
function [maxDist, thetaOpt] = SolutionL3P1(v,x)


errormax = 0.00001; 

a = 0:0.1:90; 

plot(a,x(a))


%this is the golden ratio

R = (1 + sqrt(5))/2;

%bounds
aL = 0.1;

aU =90;

d = (R-1)*(aU-aL);

a1 = aL + d;

a2 = aU - d;

    if (x(a2)>x(a1))
        aOpt = a1;
    end

    et = ((2-R) * abs(aU - aL) / aOpt) * 100;

    while (1)

        if(et<errormax)
             break
        end
        if (x(a2) > x(a1))
           aOpt = a2;
           aU = a1;   
           d = (R - 1)*(aU - aL);
           a1 = aL + d;
           a2 = aU - d;
         else
           aOpt = a1;
           aL = a2
           d = (R-1)*(aU - aL);
           a1 = aL + d;
           a2 = aU - d;
         end

         et = ((2-R)*abs(aU-aL)/aOpt)*100
     end

     maxDist = x(aOpt);
     thetaOpt = aOpt;

     hold on
     plot(thetaOpt, maxDist, 'ro')
     hold off
```

I expect it to show `thetaOpt = 45`
and `maxDist` = some number based on a user input intial velocity v...

Also, I am having issues understanding how to call this function.

Comment: Save this as a script, run the script by calling the function by typing ```SolutionL3P1(v,x)``` this on your console where v and x are your input arguments for the function

Comment: I tried >>SolutionL3P1(10,x) but gives me an error saying x is undefined variable... but im confused because x should be a output of the max distance....

Comment: x seems to be a function based on the script, have you definied the function x?